# Finding sample size necessary for a given CI

Tags: confidence-interval

I've come across a discrepancy in one of my practice questions.

I'm given the following: $\sigma=150$ units. For a 98% CI, how many observations do I need to be accurate within 15 units.

Now, the 15 refers to the width of my CI: $$w=2\cdot Z_{\frac{\alpha}{2}}\cdot \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$$

This comes from $$w=(\bar{x}+Z_{\frac{\alpha}{2}}\cdot \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}})-(\bar{x}-Z_{\frac{\alpha}{2}}\cdot \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}})$$

For a 98% CI, 2-tailed, I need the Z-score for 0.99. That is 2.33 appoximately (qnorm(.99)=2.3263).

so when I plug it in and solve for n:
$$n=(2\cdot 2.33\cdot 150/15)^2$$ $$=46.6^2=2171$$.

However, the answer given is 644.... if someone could help me out I would appreciate it.

Comment: "Accurate to within $15$ units" means the width (of a symmetric CI) is $30$.  If the answer is given as "644," though, it probably contains a typographical error.  $544$ would be close to correct.

Comment: Of course... I completely overlooked the word within. Thank you.

Comment: I would only get 543 then?

Comment: It would appear that I get 664 if I use a 99% CI instead (i.e. qnorm(.995)). Is the solution incorrect?